# Pick off Authentication header PHP

Tags: php

I am sending a token within the headers of each request, when I do a `print_r(apache_request_headers());` I get ...

```
[Host] => 192.168.100.100 
[Connection] => keep-alive 
[Authorization] =>d868cbf31f676130649fbfd7fff64a70cc071cd0fc8afa676b ... 
[Origin] => null 
[User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0; en-us; GT-I9300 Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30 
[Accept] => */* 
[Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, sdch [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.8 )
```

I have tried `echo $_SERVER['Authorization'];` but get a an error `Undefined index: Authorization`.

How do I get the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [array dereferencing (PHP >= 5.4)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing), e.g.

```
echo apache_request_headers()["Authorization"];
```

Or assign it to a variable an then access it, e.g.

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
echo $headers["Authorization"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is Server Independent

```
$header = getallheaders();
echo $header['Authorization'];
```